# MySQL: WHERE value is greater than Min and less than Max

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

This is my query:

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_title, lat.meta_value AS latitude, lng.meta_value AS longitude, info1.meta_value AS street_no, info2.meta_value AS street, info3.meta_value AS street_suffix, price.meta_value AS price,
        ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( '{$latitude}' ) ) * cos( radians( lat.meta_value ) ) * cos( radians( lng.meta_value ) - radians( '{$longitude}' ) ) + sin( radians( '{$latitude}' ) ) * sin( radians( lat.meta_value ) ) ) ) AS distance

        FROM wp_posts

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS lat 
            ON lat.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
                AND lat.meta_key = 'property_lat'

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS lng 
            ON lng.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
                AND lng.meta_key = 'property_long'

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS info1 
            ON info1.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
                AND info1.meta_key = 'street_no'

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS info2 
            ON info2.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
                AND info2.meta_key = 'street'

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS info3 
            ON info3.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
                AND info3.meta_key = 'street_suffix'

        LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS price 
            ON price.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
                AND price.meta_key = 'price_current'

        WHERE lat.meta_key IS NOT NULL

        HAVING distance < 30

        LIMIT 0, 20
```

I need to update the `WHERE` statemtent to take into account `price_min` and `price_max` values... only returning results `WHERE price is >= {$price_min} AND <= {$price_max}`

I hope that makes sense...

Comment: Have you tried this? `WHERE lat.meta_key IS NOT NULL AND price is >= {$price_min} AND <= {$price_max}` pity if you haven't :) add the correct table alias accordingly.

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax;`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are only getting one row per id, I would suggest you rewrite your query as an aggregation:

```
select p.*,
       ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians( '{$latitude}' ) ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians( '{$longitude}' ) ) + sin( radians( '{$latitude}' ) ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
from (select p.id,
             max(case when meta_key = 'property_lat' then meta_value end) as latitude,
             max(case when meta_key = 'property_long' then meta_value end) as longitude,
             max(case when meta_key = 'street_no' then meta_value end) as street_no,
             max(case when meta_key = 'street' then meta_value end) as street,
             max(case when meta_key = 'street_suffix' then meta_value end) as street_suffix,
             max(case when meta_key = 'price_current' then meta_value end) as price_current
      from wp_posts p
      group by p.id
    ) p
WHERE latitude IS NOT NULL and distance < 30
LIMIT 0, 20
```

This query is untested, so it may have syntax errors.

With this structure, you can just add:

```
price_current is >= {$price_min} AND <= {$price_max}
```

to the outer query.  I am assuming you mean price_current, since price is not in the original query.

Comment: What's the outer query in this case?

Comment: It is a way to define new columns and to use those columns in a `where` clause.  This seemed to be why you were using a `having` clause in the original query -- I find that confusing, since a `having` clause should imply a `group by`.

Comment: Error: `near 'from wp_posts p group by p.id ) p WHERE latitude IS NOT NULL and di' at line 10`